# How do I set up radio buttons in Excel?

Tags: excel, user-interface, vba

I want to use Excel to capture survey results. I want to have a large number of questions each with 5 radio buttons ranging from Excellent to Poor. Each radio button should correspond to a numerical value stored in a set of data cells somewhere (e.g Excellent = 13, Poor = 10, Good = 5 etc). I would like to be able to cut and paste these to assist in duplicating the controls for the large number of questions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can go to View -> Toolbars -> **Forms**

Then you should see the radio button which you can click on and add to your Excel sheet.

A good idea is to put down a "Group Box" first than add the Option Buttons to them. This way you can easily have many groups of questions.

You can also use the Excel **CHOOSE** function to set the values of the Option Buttons like you mentioned in your question...

See: [here](http://www.learn-ict.org.uk/materials/documents/course_notes/excel_interm/Controls/options.htm) for more details.

Comment: I can link it to a cell and specify it as checked or unchecked. Can you provide more detail on how I can go about implementing some of the features in my question?

Comment: Sorry, but I just re-wrote the answer because I found out the I was looking at ActiveX controls, not Form controls which is what you will need, please re-read my answer again and let me know how you go :)

Comment: Looks good, I can set up the controls correctly. Any idea how to then cut and paste the controls efficiently?

Comment: What exactly are you trying to do with cut and paste, is it just for replciation purposes? Have you tried to use the Group Box and Option Buttons, then just select all of them and try to copy and paste them? Whats happens?

Comment: You end up with only one set of radio buttons, i.e only one selection is possible amongst all groups.